# how to center image on the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**Hello, I'm trying to center my images in the app, but I'm not getting it.**
*What am I doing wrong? How am I going to centralize these images?*

---

```
InkWell(
    child: new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
      child: snapshot.data.Facebook != ""
          ? Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/facebook.png",
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : Row(
              children: <Widget>[],
            ),
    ),
    onTap: () async {
      if (await canLaunch(snapshot.data.Facebook)) {
        await launch(snapshot.data.Facebook);
      } else {
        throw 'erro ao tentar acessar o facebook do(a) $snapshot.data.Nome';
      }
    }),
```

I'm stopped at this

[image]

Comment: please provide a full-screen code.
Do you want those images in the center of the screen or only horizontally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `mainAxisAlignment` to align their child to `center, spaceAround, spaceBetween`, etc .

and `mainAxisSize` to provide size of `mainAxis` .

```
 InkWell(  
    child: new Padding(  
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),  
      child: snapshot.data.Facebook != ""          
      ?      
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/facebook.png",
                height: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      : Row(
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
),
onTap: () async {
  if (await canLaunch(snapshot.data.Facebook)) {
    await launch(snapshot.data.Facebook);
  } else {
    throw 'erro ao tentar acessar o facebook do(a) $snapshot.data.Nome';
  }
}),
```

Answer (score 3):

set image property like this

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  image:DecorationImage(
     fit:BoxFit.fill
     image: AssetImage("images/Ani.png"),
 )
);
```

Comment: Row widget doesn't support image parameter

Answer (score 0):

To center align the widgets in the Row widget, you can use the mainAxisAlignment property and set it to MainAxisAlignment.center.

Here is an example from your code snippet

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset("assets/images/facebook.png", height: 30),
      Image.asset("assets/images/instagram.png", height: 30),
      Image.asset("assets/images/linkedin.png", height: 30)
    ],
    ));
```